# Where can I find an index of preseed options?

Tags: debian, preseed

I'm interested in a list of all Debian and Ubuntu preseed options, more specifically preseed options for Debian. I have seen the preseed example text for Jessie, but I have no way to list all available "netcfg/*" options, for example.

Is there a manual or index somewhere?

Answer (score 9):

Like yaegashi said, there is no manual containing a full list.

What I prefer to do is run debian-installer with the kernel command line parameter `DEBCONF_DEBUG=5`. If you do this and then run the installer with preseeding enabled, then debconf will log with some verbosity what questions it's asking and the answers you're getting.

With that, you configure preseeding based on what's in the example preseed file, and then every time you get a question that you didn't preseed, you can switch to tty4 and check out what the template is.

Answer (score 7):

You can get these, with defaults, from an installed system:

> debconf-get-selections --installer

Comment: On Ubuntu, I got nothing with that command, but got everything I needed with `debconf-get-selections`. So thanks. :)

Comment: You may need to install debconf-tools to get the selections, and you may need to run with `sudo` to read some of the debconf answer databases.

Comment: apt install debconf-utils

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen such a comprehensive guide/manual/index other than [`example-preseed.cfg`](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/example-preseed.txt) in the official documents.  Therefore it's my usual way to look into sources of [Debian Installer](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) [components](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?email=debian-boot%40lists.debian.org) in order to learn details of debconf parameter meanings and d-i behaviors.

For [netcfg](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/netcfg) you can see `*.templates` files in [debian dir](https://sources.debian.net/src/netcfg/1.131/debian/) to get complete info on valid debconf parameters and docs.  Then read sources and docs in [top dir](https://sources.debian.net/src/netcfg/1.131/) to understand its usage in detail.

[Debian Installer Internals](https://d-i.debian.org/doc/internals/) would help you to grasp overview of the d-i process.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! One last question. I tried s/netcfg/partman on the netcfg url you provided to see if I could find documentation on the other options (partman, tasksel, etc) but I ended up here: https://sources.debian.net/src/partman/63/debian/partman.templates/ (the only partman dir available) which looks like it's for sarge. Any thoughts on finding the more recent partman(et al).templates for jessie? Thanks again!!

Comment: partman was divided into several sub packages, [partman-base](https://sources.debian.net/src/partman-base/) and others.  On [building d-i](https://d-i.alioth.debian.org/doc/internals/ch04.html), packages are retrieved based on [pkg-lists](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/d-i/debian-installer.git/tree/build/pkg-lists) and each package's dependency (`Depends:` in `debian/control`).  You can find possible packages [here](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?email=debian-boot%40lists.debian.org) and [there](http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/d-i/trunk/.mrconfig?revision=69260&view=markup).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Charles Plessy wrote a [Haskell program](https://people.debian.org/~plessy/debconfTemplateToHTML.hs) that parses debian-installer templates and generates a single HTML page with question titles, texts, answer types, and default values. [This page](https://people.debian.org/~plessy/DebianInstallerDebconfTemplates.html) is extremely useful when creating preseed files. Details in [this discussion](https://lists.debian.org/debian-boot/2016/09/msg00075.html).